# two events fired simultaneously in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, triggers

I have an update panel in my ASP.NET web form with a trigger that will fire a click event when the contents within my update panel is updated (it's a grid view with fields). The event that is fired when then take the changes user made and do some calculation and then update another update panel with that information. This is all fine and dandy when the user tabs along the form and fill out the form in a orderly fashion before hitting any buttons on the page.

If a user accidentally hits another button on the page while changing the content in my grid within the update panel, for example, the user enter a value in my grid view control, without tabbing, the user click the save button.

Logically, i believe that the trigger should fire the click event first (event A), and then the save button event (event B). But, consistently I haven't seen event A gets fire correctly while event B gets fire all the time ...

any thoughts on this?

is there a way to ensure event A always gets fired before event B?
also if event A update another update panel without the page will event B fire after the update is complete?

thanks.

Comment: Can you block button B by disabling it until the grid is refreshed?

Comment: @Brian, probably not since there are other components in the page and the grid view is not a required field per se .. thus a user can click the button b without having anything in the grid view.

Comment: Well what I mean is once you click the button, block the button for event B?  This is typically employed for issues like accidentially clicking a button twice, for instance.

Comment: Sorry but kind of getting lost...what is the exact issue? Any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to block the form from post 2 times before gets update. Here is an example

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
var fAlloToSubmit = true;

function AllowFormToRun()
{
if(!fAlloToSubmit)
    alert("Please wait for the page to fully re-loaded.");

return fAlloToSubmit;
}

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
   fAlloToSubmit = false;
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
   fAlloToSubmit = true;
}
```

and on code behind add the onsubmit.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"]))
        {
            Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = "return AllowFormToRun();";
        }
    }
```